# How can a macro define a valid global name based on the type passed to it?

Tags: c, generics, macros, c11

I believe the title is self-explanatory, but here's an example to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
#define PASTE2(_0, _1)  _0 ## _1

#define DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE(TYPE)                   \
    int PASTE2(do_something_with_, TYPE)(void) {    \
        /* do_something_with_<TYPE> */              \
    }
```

Everything works fine for `char`, `int`, and single-worded types, but when it
comes to `unsigned` types, or others that have multiple keywords, using token pasting (`a ## b`) does not generate a valid name due to the whitespace (e.g.: `do_something_with_foo bar`).

The easiest solution I could think of is to change the `DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE` macro
to take a valid name as the 2nd parameter. For example:

```
#define DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE(TYPE, NAME_FOR_TYPE)            \
    int PASTE2(do_something_with_, NAME_FOR_TYPE)(void) {   \
        /* do_something_with_<NAME_FOR_TYPE> */             \
    }
```

This works as expected, but I'm curious about other possible solutions, even if they're overly complex. I thought of using `_Generic`, but I fail to see how it would help in defining a name.

Can you think of another solution?

Comment: I don't know about C11, but certainly before that, macros don't have the ability to do complex string processing (e.g. replacing whitespace or characters like "*").

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Do you think a variadic macro would work for `DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE(unsigned, int)` and `DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE(unsinged, long, long)`? I'm thinking of `#define DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE(...)` and token-paste all `__VARGS__` for up to 3 arguments. But I doubt it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a macro with an empty argument. Example:

```
#define STR2(x)             # x
#define STR(x)              STR2(x)
#define PASTE3(_1,_2,_3)    _1 ## _2 ## _3
#define FOO(_1,_2,_3)       PASTE3(_1, _2, _3)

printf("%s\n", STR(FOO(int,,)));
printf("%s\n", STR(FOO(unsigned, int,)));
printf("%s\n", STR(FOO(unsigned, long, long)));
```

As you can [see here](http://codepad.org/ufEOdIeT), the output is:

```
int
unsignedint
unsignedlonglong
```

I don't remember whether using empty macro arguments is well defined according to the standard, but I can tell you that Clang 3.1 doesn't emit any warnings for `-std=c11` with `-pedantic`.

Here's some code if you want to try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define PASTE4(_1,_2,_3,_4) _1 ## _2 ## _3 ## _4

#define DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE1(T1)        DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE2(T1,)
#define DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE2(T1, T2)    DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE3(T1,T2,)
#define DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE3(T1, T2, T3)                                    \
    int PASTE4(write_,T1,T2,T3)(FILE *file, void *data) {                   \
        T1 T2 T3 foo;                                                       \
        int written = fprintf(file, fmt_specifier(foo), *((T1 T2 T3 *)data));\
        return written > 0 ? 0 : -1;                                        \
    }

#define fmt_specifier(x)                \
    _Generic((x),                       \
        int: "%i",                      \
        unsigned int: "%u",             \
        unsigned long long: "%llu",     \
        default: NULL                   \
    )

DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE1(int)
DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE2(unsigned, int)
DEFINE_OPS_FOR_TYPE3(unsigned, long, long)

int main() {
    int var_int = INT_MAX;
    write_int(stdout, &var_int);
    printf("\n");
    unsigned int var_uint = UINT_MAX;
    write_unsignedint(stdout, &var_uint);
    printf("\n");
    unsigned long long var_ullong = ULLONG_MAX;
    write_unsignedlonglong(stdout, &var_ullong);
    printf("\n");
    return 0
}
```

Comment: empty arguments are indeed well defined, there is no problem with that

Comment: You could improve that with tricks such as __VA_NARGS__ which is a popular way to count the number of arguments in a macro.

Comment: @Morwenn: Thank you for the note. The code above is just a demo. I cut many lines to fit well here. The real one uses a simpler variation of `PP_NARG` - kudos to [@JensGustedt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) and his [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr).

Comment: If anyone is curious about the usefulness of this, [here's a simple example](https://github.com/jweyrich/c11serializer/blob/master/test/test.c).

Answer (score 2):

On the level of declaration or definition of the symbols that you want to do there is not much way out of `typedef`ing things to a unique identifier for the type in question. `_Generic` or equivalent replacements kick in too late to be useful for the preprocessor.

But there is only a finite number of standard types that pose such a problem. So you can easily come up with a convention for typedeffing these.

Where `_Generic` can help is on the *usage* side of your such defined symbols. Here you can then do something like

```
_Generic((X),
  unsigned long: do_something_with_ulong,
  unsigned char: do_something with_uchar,
  ...
)(X)
```

In [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) I follow this scheme, and you would find a lot of support macros for it already in place.