# Variadic macro expansion for each token

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have a macro, a simple one that just calls a function `foo` for different type:

```
#define FOO(type) foo_##type();
```

In one go, let's say I want to call this thing for multiple different types. Concretely;

```
foo_int();
foo_float();
foo_point2d();
```

I want to generate above code with a macro called `FOO2`.

```
#define FOO2(args...) --fill--here
```

And just to be complete, `FOO2(int, float, point2d)` should expand into the above small code snippet. Is this possible with macros and how to do a different, separate thing for each argument in a variadic macro token pack?

I am sure a question like this is already asked. I searched for couple of other results, showing some sort of `FOR_EACH` macro implementation that were quite complicated and general. That's why I decided to ask for my specific use-case and started a new question.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about doing this kind of thing with macros, but the real problem to which you believe the solution involves doing this kind of thing with macros, so that's what you're asking about.

Comment: You could say, I am trying to auto generate setters and getters for my structs by using a macro annotation and I ended up needing something like this. Not that this is a good idea, just an experimentation. But really, solution to this isolated case is what I am after.

Comment: Well, the problem is that there's very little in the core C++ that can be "auto generated", and you're fighting the tide. In somewhat similar situations in the past, I used an XML definition, and some stylesheets that both generated the class declarations, as well as the methods that modified each class member. The end result was boring, garden-variety C++. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: Looking at functionality of macros like `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`, I thought this would also be possible to achieve.

Comment: This might also interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14137291/298054 - macros support empty arguments so you can have a single macro with multiple arguments and pass empty arguments if you don't care about some extra 
commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but requires multiple macros.

```
#define MAP1(m,t,...) m(t)
#define MAP2(m,t,...) m(t); MAP1(m,__VA_ARGS__)
#define MAP3(m,t,...) m(t); MAP2(m,__VA_ARGS__)
// ... add more as needed ...
#define MAP(n,...) MAP##n(__VA_ARGS__)

#define FOO(type) foo_##type()
#define FOON(n, ...) MAP(n, FOO, __VA_ARGS__)

FOON(3, int, float, double);
```

The above will generate:

```
foo_int(); foo_float(); foo_double();
```

If you don't want to specify the number as argument, add the following:

```
#define FOO1(...) FOON(1, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOO2(...) FOON(2, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOO3(...) FOON(3, __VA_ARGS__)
// ... add more as needed ...
```

And now you can just do:

```
FOO3(int, float, double);
```

---

With a bit more work you can even make the macro work with any function name:

```
#define MAP1(m,f,t,...) m(f,t)
#define MAP2(m,f,t,...) m(f,t); MAP1(m,f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define MAP3(m,f,t,...) m(f,t); MAP2(m,f,__VA_ARGS__)
// ...
#define MAP(n,...) MAP##n(__VA_ARGS__)

#define CALL(funcname, type) funcname##_##type()
#define CALLN(n, funcname, ...) MAP(n, CALL, funcname, __VA_ARGS__)

#define CALL1(...) CALLN(1, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CALL2(...) CALLN(2, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CALL3(...) CALLN(3, __VA_ARGS__)
// ...

CALL1(foo, int);
CALL2(bar, float, double);
CALL3(baz, whatever, you, want);
```

Result:

```
foo_int();
bar_float(); bar_double();
baz_whatever(); baz_you(); baz_want();
```